# Long CSS class names against inheritance performance impact

Tags: css, sass

Consider these two CSS selectors:

This, which selects each component by inheritance:

```
.app { ... }
.app .header { ... }
.app .header .search { ... }
.app .header .search form { ... }
.app .header .search form input { ... }
```

And this, which selects each component by its unique class name:

```
.app__header { ... }
.app__header__search { ... }
.app__header__search__form { ... }
.app__header__search__form__input { ... }
```

Which of these two are better for performance? Also, consider that each component can repeat from 1 to 10 times in the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Code And Example Can you Try this it's standard of BEM(Block Element Management)

**Html**

```
<form class="form form--theme-xmas form--simple">
  <input class="form__input" type="text" />
  <input
    class="form__submit form__submit--disabled"
    type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.form { }
.form--theme-xmas { }
.form--simple { }
.form__input { }
.form__submit { }
.form__submit--disabled { }
```

It is a known fact that the right style guide can significantly increase development speed, debugging, and the implementation of new features in the legacy code. Sadly, most CSS codebases are sometimes developed without any structure or naming conventions. This leads to an unmaintainable CSS codebase in the long term.

The BEM approach ensures that everyone who participates in the development of a website works with a single codebase and speaks the same language. Using proper naming will prepare you for the changes in the design of the website.

See more information http://getbem.com/naming/

Comment: Personally, I love BEM for many reasons, but sometimes it can be difficult to implement, depending on how complex the block and its elements are.

Comment: I agree with you, 100% implement difficult. because when many parents of the element then CSS class meaningfully difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the first one will be better as you can use the classes multiple times anywhere

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the first one has a smaller file size, but it abuses inheritance, and the second is the opposite and is prettier on a html file (my opinion).

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question of which is `better for performance`

Comment: If the file is smaller in size, the download speed will be faster and inheritance has a small impact on page rendering. Both of them impact performance in different ways. Also, I was testing the "answer your own question" feature :)

Comment: Everything is gzipped anyway - there's pretty much no difference at all